# postgresql disable foreign key check not working

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, docker-compose

I am working on a Symfony PHP project to migrate a mysql database to postgres and it requires to temporarily disable the foreign key checks.

I found several posts on this, but no proposed solution is working.

I tried:

```
 pg_query("SET session_replication_role = 'replica'");
```

or

```
 pg_query($connPg, 'ALTER TABLE ' . $table . ' DISABLE TRIGGER ALL' );
```

or

```
 pg_query($connPg, "SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED");
```

I am still getting the same message:

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
> DETAIL:  Table "sector_hierarchy" references "sector".
> HINT:  Truncate table "sector_hierarchy" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.

I was thinking about possible privileges issue and changed the user to superuser, but that did not help:

```
 ALTER USER root WITH SUPERUSER
```

Also when I attempt to list the triggers I get nothing in return, though I can see the FK's on pgAdmin. So this returns no rows:

```
select * from information_schema.triggers
```

For information the version for Postgres is 13.7 and this is in a docker-compose set up.

EDIT:

This is one sequence queries that triggers the error:

```
 pg_query($connPg, "ALTER USER root WITH SUPERUSER");
 pg_query($connPg, 'ALTER TABLE sfadb.' . $table . ' DISABLE TRIGGER ALL');
 pg_query($connPg, 'TRUNCATE TABLE sfadb.' . $table .' RESTART IDENTITY');
```

They are being run as part of transaction, but if I remove the transaction nothing seems to change.

As per the message above, the error is not being triggered on the target table as such, but in one of its relations.

I tried also disabling the triggers for that specific table, but still getting same error:

```
 pg_query($connPg, 'ALTER TABLE sfadb.sector_hierarchy DISABLE TRIGGER ALL');
```

Comment: Please include the table structure and the exact queries that result in this error, and if they’re being run as part of a transaction

Comment: "*it requires to temporarily disable the foreign key checks.*" - why? That seems like a really ugly hack. Can't you just use `truncate table ... cascade`?  And you should never uses a "superuser" account as the user owning your tables and which is used from within your application.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. No I can't TRUNCATE CASCADE as this would wipe out all the data I have there, which has already been migrated.

Comment: Why not then just migrate the data in the correct order that respects your foreign keys? Or create the tables without FK constraints, migrate the data (not caring about the order), then create the FK constraints once everything is correct. Or define the FK constraints as `deferrable` and migrate everything in a single transaction.

Comment: For the first option, migrate in correct order, I have table `user` that relates to `sector` and vice-versa. So order would not matter. That's exactly the issue I have now. Option 3 - migrate everything in a single transaction - not really an option. I have about 300 tables for which each migration has to be done and tested. The data is not being imported from mysql as is. It needs manipulation, cleansing. Option 2 would work, but sound like a terrible  mess to keep under control.